# Is there a way to make mvn clean install fail when tests are skipped?

Tags: maven, build

mvn clean install in my case is set up to run unit tests and integration tests. When a particular integration test is skipped for some reason, the build is still successful.

I am trying to understand if there is a way to make this fail when a test is skipped or if there is another work around for this?

Comment: What do you mean "if a particular integration test is skipped for some reason"? You mean, in the `<configuration>` or on the command line?

Comment: @JFMeier In my case, I have a set of integration tests set up using cucumber feature files. These are set up to run during the build. Now, sometimes, say we add tests in incorrect formats(which are sometimes missed during reviews), these tests tend to get skipped in the build, and the results of the integration tests run would say "Passed: 50 Skipped:1", but the build would still pass. Just trying to understand if there is a way to fail the build here even if a test is skipped this way.

Comment: So, isn't this more a question about cucumber configuration?

Comment: @JFMeier Could be one of the things to look at, but I was also trying to find out if there's any way to tell mvn to fail builds on tests being skipped as well.

Comment: You were right, changing cucumber to strict helped solve the issue. Thanks fo that.